# 2nd Order PDE with Mixed Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have this n+1-dimensional PDE which looks like a heat equation but with mixed derivatives.

$$
\frac{\partial G(\boldsymbol{\alpha},\beta,t)}{\partial t} = \boldsymbol{K}(\boldsymbol{\alpha},\beta)\, \cdot \, \frac{\partial^2 G(\boldsymbol{\alpha},\beta,t)}{\partial{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}\,\partial \beta}
$$
$$
G(\boldsymbol{\alpha},\beta,0) = \beta^b \prod^{n-1}_{i=0}\alpha_i^{a_i}
$$

where $a_i$ and $b$ are constants and $|\beta|<1,|\alpha_i|<1$ $\;\forall\, i$. I can solve it using separation of variables, but I was wondering if anyone has seen this equation or something similar that has analytic solutions without assuming separable solutions. Insight on the two dimensional case

$$
\frac{\partial G(\alpha,\beta,t)}{\partial t} = K(\alpha,\beta)\; \frac{\partial^2 G(\alpha,\beta,t)}{\partial\alpha\,\partial \beta}
$$

will be appreciated as well. Then I can generalize it to n-dimensions.

$\textit{A priori}$, it looks like one could turn it into the generalized diffusion equation

$$
\frac{\partial Q(\boldsymbol{r},t)}{\partial t} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \left[ D(\boldsymbol{r})\, \boldsymbol{\nabla}Q(\boldsymbol{r},t) \right]
$$

by cleverly using zero terms in the $D$ matrix (here $\boldsymbol{r}$ is a vector containing both $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ and $\beta$). But I wouldn't know where to go from there.

Comment: The most general solution comes from separation of variable since it provides a complete vector space. This is clear from your latest equation that contains a self-adjoint operator (provided the domain is properly defined). However, if you like a closed form, you can use heat kernel (as the fundamental solution of heat equation). Although this method again uses separation of variable, it finally gives you a solution like n-dimensional Gaussian function.

Comment: @HR-Physics Thanks. I'll just stick to the separable solution, then. Quick question regarding heat kernel: I know the heat kernel is the fundamental solution to $K_t(x,y,t) = \Delta_x K(x,y,t)$. Is there a way I could modify my PDE to have a solution written as a convolution of the heat kernel?